# Dynamodb get a single item based on sort key only

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to dynamodb and I need to process 5M records. Each record has an id and a status. I need to query for each record based on its status, process it, and finally update the status.

I am using `DynamoDbEnhancedClient` but I could not find example on how to query based only on the range and not the hash, while avoiding scan.
I tried to create a query with a condition and a limit of 1 but it did not work.

Here is what I have:

My Customer model:

```
@DynamoDbPartitionKey
private String id;
@DynamoDbSecondarySortKey(indexNames = "status")
private String status;
private String name;
```

configs:

```
@Bean
public DynamoDbEnhancedClient dynamoDbEnhancedClient(){
    return DynamoDbEnhancedClient.builder()
            .dynamoDbClient(dynamoDbClient())
            .extensions(AutoGeneratedTimestampRecordExtension.create())
            .build();
}
```

My query:

```
static final TableSchema<Customer> CUSTOMER_TABLE = TableSchema.fromClass(Customer.class);

public Customer findByStatus() {
    DynamoDbTable<Customer> customerTable = dynamoDbEnhancedClient.table("customer", CUSTOMER_TABLE);

    QueryConditional queryConditionalPerPartition = new EqualToConditional(Key.builder().
            partitionValue("status").
            build());


    QueryEnhancedRequest request = QueryEnhancedRequest.builder()
            .limit(1)
            .queryConditional(queryConditionalPerPartition)
            .build();


    PageIterable<Customer> pageIterable = customerTable.query(request);


    Customer customer = pageIterable.stream().findFirst().get().items().get(0);
    return customer;
}
```

However that does not work. How can query by status and only get a single result?
I have no restriction on the table structure and I can change it however I require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally figured it out, I needed to create create a [GSI (Global Secondary Index)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html)

When creating the GCI you define the the sort key as hash key and than you can query the index.

create table:

```
aws dynamodb create-table \
--table-name customer \
 --key-schema \
    AttributeName=id,KeyType=HASH \
    AttributeName=status,KeyType=RANGE \
--attribute-definitions \
    AttributeName=id,AttributeType=S \
    AttributeName=status,AttributeType=S \
--provisioned-throughput \
    ReadCapacityUnits=5,WriteCapacityUnits=5 \
--table-class STANDARD \
--global-secondary-index '[
    {
  \"IndexName\": \"id-status\",
  \"KeySchema\": [
    {
       \"AttributeName\": \"status\",
      \"KeyType\": \"HASH\"
    },
    {
       \"AttributeName\": \"id\",
      \"KeyType\": \"RANGE\"
    }
  ],
  \"Projection\": {
    \"ProjectionType\": \"ALL\"
  },
  \"ProvisionedThroughput\": {
    \"ReadCapacityUnits\": 1,
    \"WriteCapacityUnits\": 1
  }
}
]'
```

My model in Java:

```
@DynamoDbBean
public class Customer {

private String id;
private String status;
private Instant created;
private Instant updated;

public Customer(){


@DynamoDbPartitionKey
@DynamoDbSecondarySortKey(indexNames = "id-status")
public String getId() {
    return id;
}

@DynamoDbSortKey
@DynamoDbSecondaryPartitionKey(indexNames = "id-status")
public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}


@DynamoDbAutoGeneratedTimestampAttribute
@DynamoDBTypeConverted(converter = InstantToStringTypeConverter.class)
public Instant getCreated() {
    return created;
}

@DynamoDbAutoGeneratedTimestampAttribute
@DynamoDBTypeConverted(converter = InstantToStringTypeConverter.class)
public Instant getUpdated() {
    return updated;
 }
}
```

Than query the db:

```
@Service
public class customerDAO {

static final TableSchema<customer> CUSTOMER_TABLE = 
TableSchema.fromBean(Customer.class);

@Autowired
private DynamoDbEnhancedClient dynamoDbEnhancedClient;


public Customer findByStatus() {


    DynamoDbTable<Customer> customerTable = dynamoDbEnhancedClient.table("customer", CUSTOIMER_TABLE);



    DynamoDbIndex<Customer> secIndex = customerTable.index("id-status");



    QueryConditional queryConditional = QueryConditional
            .keyEqualTo(Key.builder().partitionValue("PENDING").
                    build());


    PageIterable<Customer> results =
            (PageIterable<Customer>) secIndex.query(QueryEnhancedRequest.builder().
                    .queryConditional(queryConditional)
                    .build());
    results.forEach(p -> p.items().forEach(item -> System.out.println(customer)));

  }
 }
```